# Variance in computer processing speed

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to figure out how much time one of my algorithm would need to work.
In order to do so, I built a simple python script (I reckon I have a foolish approach in this alg, not testing much):

```
import time

n=0
x=[]
for k in range(1,10):
    begin = time.time()
    while  (n<1E7):
        n+=1
    end = time.time()
    x.append(end-begin)
    print(x)
    n=0
print(x)
```

The result on my computer is:

```
[2.755953550338745, 2.234074831008911, 2.719917058944702, 2.4802486896514893, 2.8635189533233643, 2.7834832668304443, 4.048354387283325, 3.454935312271118, 3.3593692779541016]
```

Without doing any further analysis, I can't help but notice a pretty large variance in this result. Where can it be coming from ?

Comment: Have you considered using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)?

Comment: My question isn't really about how to calculate my computer's speed, rather than why the results I got there are not consistent

Comment: Those look pretty consistent to me; why do you think they are not consistent? They're within a couple seconds of each other.

Comment: Try [these](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/222592/why-execution-time-is-different-each-time-in-java) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608967/why-does-the-execution-time-vary).

Comment: @EricLippert `>>> 100 * (2.755953550338745 - 2.234074831008911) / 2.234074831008911`
`23.359948023502547`
23% is a pretty significant difference

Comment: Because I have a close to 100% increase between x[1] and x[-3]. Do you reckon this is irrelevant?

Comment: You haven't demonstrated a 23% difference; you've demonstrated a few hundred millisecond difference. When you've run it and it takes 100 hours once and 123 hours a second time, then you've shown a 23% difference!

Comment: @SebVC: The noise is close to the size of the signal. Make the signal bigger.  Run a test for twenty minutes or a few days or something and then you'll have a sensible basis for comparison.

Comment: What you should do if you want to understand this better is run 100 tests.  Ten times with `n<1E1`, ten times with `n<1E2`, up to `n<1E10`, and then graph the results.  You will quickly see where the noise is and how it compares to the signal.

Comment: I reckon if I run it for a few hours all the noise will disappear. However, I am specifically asking where it may be coming from?. Will do your suggested test.

Comment: Well start with the obvious.  **Is there any other process whatsoever running on your computer**? On Windows the quantum is about 15 milliseconds, so if there are ten other processes running, and they happen to get scheduled, that's 150 milliseconds right there.

Comment: Does your machine have storage? Is that storage storing your program?  Is the storage mechanism an **enormous metal platter spinning in space**?  Have you accounted for the time it takes to spin that platter in space?

Comment: Now we go back to the first question again. **Is there any other process on your machine that is also accessing that spinning platter**?  If yes, then your process might have to wait for the disk to spin to the right place.  Does your disk have a cache?  **What's the cache policy**?  Is there any other code on your machine that could be causing your code to move out of the cache?

Comment: Speaking of caches, what's the cache line size on your processor?  Does your program have good or bad cache locality?  What are the consequences of hot spots in your program falling out of the cache?

Comment: What I'm getting at here is that your mental model of a computer is like a perfect worker that does the same thing every time you ask.  It is not. It's more like an anthill of furious activity where there are thousands of barely-coordinated processes all trying to get their own work done, and the operating system and hardware barely keeping them from killing each other.  You shouldn't expect repeatability on the small scale in an environment like that.

Comment: Would I get more consistency on small scale say an Arduino card then? Also, I thought variables in such a script would be stored in RAM, hence with little accessing time ?

Comment: I don't know. But I know a great way to find out.